# MySQL - One-to-Many Join Statement Returns Duplicates

Tags: mysql, duplicates, left-join

I have a `tbl_customers` table.  (like many of do)

I have a second table:  `tbl_customers_tags`

This table simply let's me store unlimited keywords/tags for a single client record.
Here's the columns structure:

```
`tbl_customers_tags`

+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| customerid  | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tagid       | mediumint(5)unsigned| NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

---

So, I'm now needing to pull some reports, by looking for any client records with certain tagid's.  I'm getting duplicates.
Here's my current query statement:

```
SELECT  c.firstname, c.lastname, c.datecreated  
FROM `tbl_customers` c 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_customers_tags` ctags ON c.customerid = ctags.customerid 
WHERE ctags.tagid IN(2,3,15)
```

Is there a way to not return duplicates, when a single `customerid` is associated to multiple `tagid` records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  c.firstname, c.lastname, c.datecreated  
FROM 'tbl_customers' c 
where exists
( select 'x' from tbl_customers_tags where customerid = c.customerid and
tagid IN(2,3,15)
)
```

If you are only interested in customers that have records in the tags table, why not do a full join instead of a left?

Comment: I would avoid using DISTINCT. If you really only expect one row/customer, then fix the query to do that.  Why have the database spend time fetching rows that you then discard?

Comment: Why avoid using DISTINCT?  If there's a good reason, I would love to know why.

Comment: There are valid uses for DISTINCT.  Maybe you need distinct values for one or two columns from a table for a pick list.  Where I have ususally seen this misused, is that someone has a complex query that may be missing some constraint, and getting duplicates.  They use DISTINCT as a "band-aid" to remove the duplicates instead of correcting the query.  This is just my personal view. Google "sql distinct bad" for some valid arguments.

Comment: I liked your statement, it allows me to keep it all in one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  distinct c.firstname, c.lastname, c.datecreated  
FROM `tbl_customers` c 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_customers_tags` ctags ON c.customerid = ctags.customerid 
WHERE ctags.tagid IN(2,3,15)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't care for duplicates, you can use the `DISTINCT` keyword.  Also, you don't need to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` since you have a `WHERE` clause dependent on the other table.  Something like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT c.firstname, c.lastname, c.datecreated  
FROM `tbl_customers` c 
JOIN `tbl_customers_tags` ctags 
ON c.customerid = ctags.customerid 
WHERE ctags.tagid IN (2,3,15)
```